# How to disable the modal close upon button press

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a login form in modal window. The problem is when I click on the sign in button, and if the login credentials are wrong, the modal closes. User needs to click again on the sign in button to see the modal and the error message.

How can I solve this?

This is the modal content.

```
<div id="signin" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
                <?php include "view/login.html";  ?>
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

`login.html` file.

```
<section class="frontoffice" style="padding: 20px 0;">
    <div class="">
        <h3 class="text-center" style="font-weight:700">SIGN IN</h3>
        <div class="row">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 request-form">
                <div class="form-area">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="text-field" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username*" style="width:100%">
                            <?php echo $unameerror; ?>
                            <input class="text-field" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password*" style="width:100%">
                            <?php echo $passerror; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin:20px;">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" name="login" class="blueButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='popup']").popover();
});
```

Comment: show me you code in here or jsfiddle

Comment: what you have write in the javascript code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input type='submit'/>` automatically posts a form, once pressed. So the page should be refreshed after button press. You should use ajax to send the form and post back the response. It should look like this:

```
$(function(){

 $("form").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("url", $(this).serialize(), function(response){
    //present errors
  }, "json");
  })
})
```

---

On the php side, set the response as an array, and use `echo json_encode($array)` to present the result.

Hope i got it this time :D

Comment: Where should I apply this? Could you give me a jfiddle if possible?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so good with AJAX. WHere should I write the php code for user login?

Comment: Ajax is just the same as submitting the code (it just does it behind the scenes without refreshing the page). You need to replace the `url` în the javascript i wrote with the url to which you would send the form with regular php. And in the php file, store the result in an array like: `$result = ["success"=>true]` or `$result=["error"=>true, "error_message"=>"Wrong password"]` and after that `echo json_encode($result)`. The result will be passed to the javascript in the `function(response)` callback, the `response` variable containing the result as an object.

Comment: I want to pass the username and password to the `login.html` file. That's the action page. And after processing, I need to return a variable with some error message or redirect to the account page. Could you add this to the function you created?

Comment: Aren't you using php? How are you processing the data?

Comment: the php is in the login.html file itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63107/discussion-between-dnu-mihai-florian-and-user1012181).

Comment: Actually I wrote the HTML code for the login form and the authentication php in the file `login.php` and included that login.php file in the model widnow in index.html